# SendGrid - Email not sending / PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to go through SendGrid in order to send emails through my contact form from my website.  My code is not throwing back any errors but the emails are still not being delivered.  A 202 status code is not being produced and therefore the result is coming back as false

Please, could the PHP experts out there have a quick look and see where I am making the mistake.  As I am not receiving any errors I am totally lost!

```
require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $FROM_EMAIL = 'test@test.com';
    $TO_EMAIL = 'test@test.com';


    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $FROM_EMAIL);
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $TO_EMAIL);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain",$name, $email, $phone, $company, $message);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($subject, $from, $to, $content);
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('API-KEY'));

    $response = $sendgrid->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

    if ($response->statusCode() == 202) {
    // Successfully sent
      echo 'done';
    } else {
      echo 'false';
    }

  }
```

Comment: Have you turned on error_reporting?

Comment: I would first all variables. Are they filled, then check your object. Check the statuscode of the object. If there is no statuscode, something else goes wrong,.

Comment: Yes, error reporting is on and nothing is thrown back.  The form is processed but echo's false.  I am unsure how I can check this further :(

Comment: As you say, the stratus code is not 202 which is confirmed when 'false' is echoed. What do you get if you echo the response that is returned (i.e. check the status code as suggested above)? e.g. echo $response->statusCode();